# Trouble Creating a webpage

Tags: python, django, view, blogs

I'm having trouble creating a view. Down below you can find my view. I keep getting template error. I'm not sure where I went wrong..

```
class PrivacyView(CreateView):
   model = Post
   template_name = 'privacy_policy.html'

   fields = '__all__'

   def form_valid(self, form):
       form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
       return super().form_valid(form)

   success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')
```

```
def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
   posts = Post.published.all()

   tag = None
   if tag_slug:
       tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
       posts = posts.filter(tags__in=[tag])

   query = request.GET.get("q")
   if query:
       posts = Post.published.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(tags__name__icontains=query)).distinct()

   paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)  # 10 posts in each page
   page = request.GET.get('page')
   try:
       posts = paginator.page(page)
   except PageNotAnInteger:
       # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
       posts = paginator.page(1)
   except EmptyPage:
       # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
       posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

   return render(request, 'post_list.html', {'posts': posts, page: 'pages', 'tag': tag})
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong here. If you can provide any help, please do.

Comment: share your project structure and settings.py file

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the return
`return render(request, 'post_list.html', {'posts': posts, page: 'pages', 'tag': tag})`
In passing the 'pages' variable, you mixed up the order, so it should be.
`return render(request, 'post_list.html', {'posts': posts, 'pages': page, 'tag': tag})`

This won't throw an error, but some data will not be passed to the webpage.

Comment: Currently, I'm getting a no reverse match error. If I had to guess it has to with how my Privacy view is rendered. I'm doing something wrong there.